# Installing Python-Tesseract on a Linux system

Tags: python, linux, runtime-error, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am having trouble installing python-tesseract on my linux system. I've been using this tutorial:
http://delimitry.blogspot.be/2014/10/installing-tesseract-for-python-on.html

The error I get is:

```
 File does not exist:['/usr/include/tesseract/capi.h', '/usr/local/include/tesseract/capi.h', '/opt/include/tesseract/capi.h', '/opt/local/include/tesseract/capi.h']
root@opencv:/home/philipp/python-tesseract#
```

When running `python setup.py clean` in `/python-tesseract` after following the rest of the instructions in order.

Running linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 on this system.

`Whereis tesseract-ocr` returns:

```
/usr/share/tesseract-ocr
```

`Whereis leptonica` returns:

```
/usr/include/leptonica
```

`Whereis tesseract` returns:

```
tesseract: /usr/bin/tesseract /usr/bin/X11/tesseract /usr/include/tesseract/ /usr/share/man/man1/tesseract.1.gz
```

I've also tried running a few other tutorials/guides to install python-tesseract that have returned other errors such as, missing libleptonica then missing libc6 but I havn't investigated these as much. Just tried to see if any other guides worked immidiately.
Also, when I run tesseract in the terminal it works, but import tesseract does not.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this and install python-tesseract?

Comment: Hum. I'd start by installing `libleptonica` and `libc6`. Right now, it seems like you have tesseract installed, but not the python bindings for tesseract. Alternatively, it seems to be available via `pip`.

Comment: You should use one of the already existuing tesseract buildpacks, like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363547/how-to-deploy-pytesseract-to-heroku

Answer (score 1):

I think this way could work for you:

1- download python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu3_vivid_amd64.deb from [here](https://bitbucket.org/3togo/python-tesseract/downloads/)

2- install gdebi-core

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

3- install python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu3_vivid_amd64.deb with gdebi

```
sudo gdebi python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this would solve the issue?

Comment: In this way, we would get python-tesseract almost ready for working. The only remaining is to configure the environment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX, with something like this, in terminal:  export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/ . I had problems for installing python-tesseract on ubuntu 14.04. When I tried to install the .deb file, the installation had problems with dependencies, issue solved with gdebi-core, that allows to install the dependencies needed for a .deb. I hope it helps.

Comment: You should use one of the already existuing tesseract buildpacks, like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363547/how-to-deploy-pytesseract-to-heroku